# PHP - Search a string for specific values, return related text

Tags: php, regex, string, pdf

I'm using a PDF reader for PHP to load a big `.pdf` file that will store each page as a seperate, huge string in a big array.

This results in an output like this:

```
"Official certificate Surname: Doe First Name: John Date of birth: 
10th of June, 1970 Place of Birth etc etc..."
```

How do I search for the specific text **"Surname"** and then select whatever text comes after that until **"First Name"** to return it as `$var_surname`.
The syntax used in the `.pdf` file will always be the same, so I have no problem using such absolute conditions for searching for the text.

I genuinely don't know where to start. Sorry if this question feels vague, let me know if more information is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(preg_match('/Surname:[\s]+([\w]+)[\s]+First/i', $input, $matches)){
    echo $matches[1];
}
```

will echo `Doe`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function like `strrpos()` to find out where the string surname ends, at what position. Then you could use `strpos()` to find out there the strin first name starts, what position. Afthr you know the positions you could chop between them and store it as `$var_surnam` . (using `substr()`). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to figuring out the pattern and then write some methods. After that just pass the string by calling the methods. Based on given information this my best possible answer. Surely you will need to use builtin String methods.